# Can I use an InterleavedBufferAttribute for indices?

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have this code snippet:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const indices = new THREE.InterleavedBufferAttribute(...);
geometry.setIndex(indices); // this is invalid
```

The last line results in a compiler error:

> Type 'InterleavedBufferAttribute' is missing the following properties from type 'Bufferattribute': dynamic, updateRange, version, needsUpdate and 12 more.

Can I even use an `InterleavedBufferAttribute` to set my indices somehow?

On a sidenote: Can you use interleaved arrays for indices in general? I mean language independent. I have never seen one. This is obviously not the main question, but I am interested.

Comment: What do you plan on interleave on the `indices` attribute? It has an item size of `1`, so you can't even pack 3 indices together. Check this [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_interleaved_dynamic.html) to see how you can pack different types of data on the same buffer.

Comment: No, you can not interleave indices in general. Interleaving indices makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not interleave indices in general. Interleaving indices makes no sense.

What would you interleave them with?

In general you interleave things like positions, normals, texture coordinates, colors. Instead of having 4 attributes with parallel arrays

```
position, position, position, position
normal, normal, normal, normal
uv, uv, uv, uv,
color, color, color, color
```

You have an interleaved array

```
pos,nrm,uv,clr,pos,nrm,uv,clr,pos,nrm,uv,clr,pos,nrm,uv,clr
```

Now come indices. Let't say we're making quad so there are 4 vertices
and 6 indices. How do you interleave 6 indices with 4 vertices? You can't

indices reference the stuff in the attributes, they aren't attributes themselves.